# VBA Error 13 & 94, comparison of Strings

Tags: vba, excel, types, comparison

I started with VBA just this week and I am having some touble with my code. I tried a few approaches but it boils down to the always same issue: Type Missmatch Error 13 when I want to assign some values from my range to strings.

```
        orig_String = m_Data(counter).Text
        repl_String = var_src(counter).Text
        repl_unit_String = unit_src(counter).Text                
        If repl_String <> orig_String Then
```

Typecasting CStr(...) or using .Text instead of .Value didn't work either.

**EDIT:** After adjusting the code to suggestions from the comments, I run into:
*Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null*

in the same place.

So before I corrected that issue there is no chance to test the rest of the code.

Can anyone give me a hint on what I do wrong? Spent two hours reading SO and experimenting and I am sure it must be obvious, but it isn't to me.

```
    Sub rename_Channel(ByRef WB As Workbook, ByRef WS As Worksheet)
        ' Compare Variables from var_src with Variables of m_Data (Row 1), if var_src VarName not found
        ' in m_Data, make new column fill values with "MISSING", if found but in different order,
        ' make it next to ensure data always has the same pattern.

        'pseudocode - what do I want to do here?
        'from worksheet get: items_to_rename
        'for column in originalWS do:
        '   if find column.entry in items_to_rename:
        '   copy column to new_Worksheet.last+1
        '   new_column.name = channelstoRename.replace(name)
        '   new_column.unit = channelsToRename.replacement(unit)


        Dim Variablen As Worksheet
        Dim m_DataStripped As Worksheet

        Dim var_src As Range
        Dim unit_src As Range
        Dim m_Data As Range
        Dim orig_String As String
        Dim repl_String As String
        Dim repl_unit_String As String
        Dim counter As Integer

        Set WS_Vars = WB.Worksheets("Variablen") '"lookup" table
        Set WS_Orig = WS
        Set var_src = WS_Vars.Range("B4:B261") 'column with replacement names
        Set unit_src = WS_Vars.Range("D4:D261") 'column with replacement units
        Set m_Data = WS_Orig.Rows(1) 'row with original names
        counter = 0


        For Each I In m_Data

        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 259 Then
           Exit Sub
        End If

        orig_String = m_Data(counter).Text
        repl_String = var_src(counter).Text
        repl_unit_String = unit_src(counter).Text                
        If repl_String <> orig_String Then
                If Not m_Data.Find(repl_String) Is Nothing Then
                    m_DataStripped.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Value = repl_String
                    m_DataStripped.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Value = repl_unit_String
                    'Copy Values into first empty Col to the right
                    m_Data.Find(repl_String).Copy (m_DataStripped.Cells(3, 1).End(xlToRight))
                Else
                  If m_Data.Find(repl_String) Is Nothing Then
                    m_DataStripped.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Value = repl_String
                    m_DataStripped.Cells(3, 1).End(xlToRight).Value = "MISSING"
                  End If
                End If
            End If
         Next

    End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to commenters and answers I managed to get it working, replacing

```
    For Each I In m_Data
```

With:

```
    For Each I In m_Data.Columns
```

And

```
    orig_String = m_Data(counter).Text
    repl_String = var_src(counter).Text
    repl_unit_String = unit_src(counter).Text
```

With:

```
    string_to_replace = var_src.Cells(counter, 1).Text
    repl_unit_String = unit_src.Cells(counter, 2).Text
    orig_String = I.Text
```

Thanks for the effort everyone.

Comment: `For Each I In m_Data` is looping through cells, so `m_Data(I)` makes no sense. There are also more cells in the m_Data than in the other two ranges so you'll run into problems there too.

Comment: Would help if you highlighted the Line of Code that is causing this issue !

Comment: @Rory just figured that in the instant. Thanks still for pointing it out

Comment: @PaulFrancis Since there is only one point where I assign to strings I didn't consider it neccessary. But you are probably right. Adjusted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `I` that you assign in your FOR loop `For Each I In m_Data` ends up being an individual cell. That's what the for loop statement says "For each Cell in the m_data range". A cell is also a `range` object.

Furthermore your lines

```
    orig_String = m_Data(counter).Text
    repl_String = var_src(counter).Text
    repl_unit_String = unit_src(counter).Text
```

Are saying "Assign m_data(1).text to orig_string" This makes no sense. There is no such thing as m_data(1). There might be an `m_data("A" & counter)`, or`m_data.offset(0,counter)` or an `m_data.cells(counter, 1)`...  Instead just refer to the I range that you are assigning in the for loop:

```
    orig_String = I.Text
    repl_String = I.Text
    repl_unit_String = I.Text
```

That says "For range 'I', get the text and stick it in orig_string"

Comment: Ok... so I thought since I assigned a one dimensional array to m_data ( the content of Row1 ) I could access it just as I would do with an array. That whole cell and row and column thing is completely new to me...

Comment: But if I assigned I.Text to every of my variables they'd all be the same. However I wanted the value of specific columns at row I to be copied to the variables. Or did I just get you completely wrong here?